# MFMailComposeViewController is this supposed to actually sendmail from the simulator?

Tags: iphone, email

I am working with MFMailComposeViewController and all seems good. The class indicates the mail was sent, but I have never setup email on the simulator and don't know how.  So if its sent, what email server did it send it to?

The [mailClass canSendMail] also returns YES so it thinks its all ok.

Does anyone know how to setup the simulator for testing this 100%

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't MFMailComposeViewController send messages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804027/why-wont-mfmailcomposeviewcontroller-send-messages)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, the simulator does not actually support email accounts or allow you to really send mail.

`[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` returns YES to allow you to fully test your mail generation and compose code paths. As far as your app should be concerned, it behaves exactly like a real device (since the user can choose to cancel out anyways on the real thing), although you cannot inspect the actual contents of the resulting email without testing on a real device.